# MySQL (Workbench) group by operation on large dataset (30GB)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, workbench, bigdata

I have a large dataset, wim.tr_2012, with columns Year, Month, Day, and Lane. I'm trying to group by Year, Month, and Day and count number of rows for each group. I used:

```
SELECT `Station Number`, Month, Day, Year, COUNT(`Lane`)
FROM wim.tr_2012
GROUP BY `Station Number`, Month, Day, Year
```

The message says:

> Error Code 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

Could anyone tell me what happened? I tried some simple queries such as `select * From wim.tr_2012`, and it works just fine.

Thank you

Comment: its because your size of database ...

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to split a date into 3 separate columns.

Comment: The simple `SELECT *...` is faster because Workbench delivers the first few rows, then quits.  With the `GROUP BY`, it must read the entire table before it can start delivering output.

Answer (score 0):

increase mysql session time by going through following 
steps

```
edit > preference >sql editor > mysql session
```